# Update statement taking too long to execute

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, cardinality

I am running a Simple Update statement. Its taking too long to execute. Here are the Update  and index details.

The default value of Exported column is 0

```
UPDATE PAR_ITM SET exported = -1 WHERE exported < 1
```

Indexes:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PAR_ITM_Exported_1]
ON [dbo].[PAR_ITM] ([exported] ASC)
WITH (
  PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = ON, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
  IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON,
  ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Please format this using code blocks. It's not readable at all.

Comment: the query plan would be useful

Comment: What is the full table definition and execution plan?

Answer (score 3):

So you are setting exported to -1 where exported already equals -1.  Maybe changing your were clause to WHERE exported = 0 would hit fewer rows?

Answer (score 3):

**Cardinality is low**
You are suffering for a problem called `low cardinality`.
See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28data_modeling%29).

**The problem**
In short every database (I know of) will refuse to use an index on a low cardinality column.

**There's more**
A ***good*** database will also refuse to use an index if it guesses that many rows will be hit by the select ***(low cardinality of the select)***, even if the column itself has lots of different values ***(high cardinality of the column)***

**Why will --insert DB here-- not use an index?**
Here's the problem.
If more than 50% (differs per database) of all rows in a database have the same value, the DB will not use the index, because it would be pointless to use an index.

It is pointless to do 2 reads for most of the rows (read 1 for the index, read 2 for the table), if you can do one read (on the table itself).
The DB has to read most rows anyway, so it just goes ahead and reads them.
The fact that the DB has to fall back on using its slowest access mechanism (full table scan) is what's causing your slowness.

**The solution**
Increase the cardinality of the column or increase the cardinality of the select.
In other works make sure you select less than 50% of all rows, and make sure than SQL-server knows (or can guess) this.

**How does the DB know the cardinality of a column?**
A good DB keeps stats on tables and columns whilst doing selects/updates/inserts. In this manner it has the info it needs to make informed decisions.

**Will forcing the use of an index speed up the query?**
No, it will slow it down.

**SO links**
[MySQL: low cardinality/selectivity columns = how to index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386852/mysql-low-cardinality-selectivity-columns-how-to-index)
[Indexing & alternatives for low-selectivity columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185378/indexing-alternatives-for-low-selectivity-columns)

Comment: The OP has told us precisely nothing about how selective the predicate is.

Comment: @Martin Smith, the statement: `UPDATE PAR_ITM SET exported = -1 WHERE exported < 1` is a pretty strong hint the update query is hitting a large percentage of the rows every time.

Answer (score 1):

Might be helpful to know how many records are included in this:

```
Select Count(*)
FROM PAR_ITM 
WHERE exported < 1
```

Basically how many rows are being updated.  Granted, even a million rows would be done relatively quickly.

Do other types of queries execute slowly on your server?

Comment: Other queries are not slow on server. There are almost 65,000 rows in the table.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should be using a non-clustered index here, as it appears there is no uniqueness to `exported` at all. The rule of thumb for non-clustered indexes is 95% uniqueness, because the query optimizer may not use the index otherwise, which means that you're slowing it down for no reason.

Take a look at this article for explanations on non-clustered index:

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/nonclustered-indexes/

Comment: then what is the other option if I drop the non clustered index on exported column

Comment: I think your query might run faster just by removing it. Remember, indexes speed up selects, but slow down inserts and updates. If a column is not a good candidate for indexing, it could impact the performance of inserts and updates considerably.

Comment: I have removed the index. I checked the query execution plan, the major (60%) cost is in the update clustered index. This column exported is also in the clustered index along with several other columns

Comment: Can you remove the index from that column altogether. That column should not be indexed at all. Did the query execute any faster after removing the non-clustered index?

Comment: `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_PAR_ITM_Exported] ON [dbo].[PAR_ITM] 
(
 [Business_Date] ASC,
 [Store_ID] ASC,
 [exported] ASC,
 [Item_Discount_Number_RRN] ASC,
 [Combo_Number] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [Discount_Name],
[Item_Discount_Amount],
[Item_Void_Reason]) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = ON, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


`  this is the non clustered index on table

Answer (score 1):

You could also be involved in  a blocking situation with another query.

Comment: The query is not being blocked