# Lesser the number of indexes means faster inserts, updates and deletes?

Tags: sql

I heard that "Lesser the number of indexes means faster inserts, updates and deletes". Is this correct? If yes, then why?

Comment: Did you read the SO rules?

Comment: I don't know if you're using Oracle, but [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141232/how-many-database-indexes-is-too-many) is a pretty good read.

Comment: at least he got his answer before the question got closed.

Comment: @DanBracuk - Is there any way i could have improved this question or is it just "bad"? Perhaps this would make it worth re-opening - So an index is just a way to sort data in a column and keep that sort order handy for quickly accessing the column elements ? If we update a non-indexed column, then performance should not be affected, right ?

Comment: It's not a programming question.  You earlier asked if your question broke the rules, and it's still not clear whether you have not read them or simply interpreted them differently than I did.  The 5 people who closed your question seem to share my interpretation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes it's correct.

Indexes make select queries run faster.  However, whenever you write you your tables, the indexes have to be updated as well, and that takes time.

Comment: Just to add: obviously the more indexes you have, the slower the process becomes.

Comment: only makes select queries run faster of the where clause has columns that have indexes ...

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=sql%20index%20how%20do%20they%20help%20select%20queries? replace sql with your database name like my-sql

Comment: So an index is just a way to sort data in a column and keep that sort order handy for quickly accessing the column elements ? If we update a non-indexed column, then performance should not be affected, right ?

Comment: @davidblaine: for MVCC databases (Postgres, MySQL/Innodb and some others), index would have to be updated even if you update non-indexed column

Comment: @mvp - where can i read about that ?

Comment: You have a typo, I guess, _whenever you write __to__ your tables_.

Answer (score 3):

YES

It is important to know how the indexes work.

The indexes (you create) are secondary and most often using B+ trees or something similar.
The values in these trees point to records you have in your database so the `SELECT` clauses using the indexed columns are faster as they can be found quickly in the tree (faster than just checking each line) but the `update`, `insert` and `delete` in the database needs also the indexes to be updated which slows the process.