# SQL Server putting Index on left join

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, indexing

I have database with around 50.000 records. Let say that I have this query (it is just a part) in stored procedure (using c# + sqlserver):

```
SELECT .... 
FROM
Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
LEFT JOIN Table3 t3 ON t2.ColumnName=t3.ColumnName
WHERE 
ISNULL(t1.ColumnName,'') LIKE @arg1 //FAST
ISNULL(t2.ColumnName2,'') LIKE @arg2//SLOW
ISNULL(t3.ColumnName,'') LIKE @arg3 //SLOW
```

If I search after t3.Column2 a Query is slow.
If I look after some t1 column (where is not left join), then it works like a charm, very fast. What is the problem? How can I speed up this? I tried to not use joins but it's not possible. 
Can I put some index on tables? On which in this particiular case?

Comment: It would help to know what you are searching for - what is @arg1 ?  Are there any indexes on t1.ColumnName or t3.ColumnName2 ?

Comment: It's value of textbox - search parameter, let say name of person.

Comment: Yes, index is on t1.Id (Clustered). I think it's automatically generated.

Comment: First thing, you don't need `ISNULL`. 2nd, searching over a text column while using `LIKE` may take a lot of time you need to tell us more than that.

Comment: Yes I need ISNULL, because that column can also be null, but I need to show other columns which are not null anyway. I need Like because he can type just a part of whole word and results should be also displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the below options and see if the performance improves. You may also try 'Execution Plan' for any index suggestions.

Create an index on,

- ColumnName in t2 & ColumnName in t3
- If above didn't help add one more index on ColumnName2 in t2

P.S. Indexes will have an impact on update/insert/delete, more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141232/how-many-database-indexes-is-too-many).

Edit - Updated as per the edited question

Comment: So there won't be any performance speed up if I use only Select statements? Because I never update or insert anything (read-only).

Comment: If it is mostly read only, then adding indexes will definitely improve performance of select statements.

Comment: I missed something, sorry. Can you rewrite your instrouction beacuse I rewrite code (I missed something)? See current code on my post. Thanks for your time, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks, but no sugnificant change. You talk about creating non-clustered-Index, right?

Comment: yes, non-clustered index. As @Tzah has suggested ISNULL is not required in your case. You can try removing it, like `t1.ColumnName LIKE @arg1 OR t2.ColumnName2 LIKE @arg2`...

Comment: "Yes I need ISNULL, because that column can also be null, but I need to show other columns which are not null anyway. I need Like because he can type just a part of whole word and results should be also displayed." 
I will accept your answer.

Comment: is your question answered? if not pls un-accept the answer and wait for better answers..

Comment: You made a great explanation, but I don't see any other appropriate solution.